# Openshift obtain number of pods

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

There's anyway using OpenShift command `oc` to obtain the current number of replicas?. I'm doing an auto scaling logic and I would need to know the current number of pods, in oder to do number_of_pods +1 for the replica number update.

Comment: You should be able to read that information from the associated `Deployment` or `ReplicaController`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just want the number, since I’m implementing a program

Comment: ...and you should be able to get that number from resources I suggested.

Comment: Yes but it return a lot of information, not only the number of pods. I was looking for something like “oc get number pods deployment” —-> 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oc client, as well as kubectl, can do this with the `jsonpath` or the `go-template` options. Here's how to get the number of replicas for a Deployment:

```
kubectl get deploy -n ci ssp-kube -o "jsonpath={.metadata.name} => {.status.availableReplicas}"
ssp-kube => 1
```

Or all deployments in that namespace:

```
kubectl get deploy -n ci  -o "jsonpath={.items[*].status.availableReplicas}"
1 2 2 ...
```

Looking at your deployments configurations, you should be able to figure out which keys to extract.

---

Now, you mention working on auto-scaling: have you considered HorizontalPodAutoscalers ? With OpenShift, you probably have the required metrics server gathering cpu/memory usages (check with `oc adm top pods` / `oc adm top nodes`).

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Comment: Thanks, I read the auto scale, the problem is, that is not the CPU or Memory what I want to use to Scale, but the service latency